# Code archive? what do people use?

Tags: programming-languages

I have loads of notepad , js , .cs in a folder that I use to refer back to when I'm developing. They are just in a folder on my laptop. Is anyone aware of a better way of storing all this guff in a more stuctured way? Thinking some kind of cloud website or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wiki for this kind of thing. There are wikis that are local, such as [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).

One way or another, to keep things safe, you should use source control, and/or backup to the cloud.

Comment: Perhaps Google Docs or similar would be good for this kind of thing? It supports tagging and searching.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my code samples that aren't project-specific in a revision-controlled directory tree, based on the language they're in; actual projects are also kept in revision control, but are kept separately.  I have tons of them now.

For smaller idioms and snippets that are useful or that I forget as I switch between languages for a period of time, I pop them into a wiki, with different pages also based on which language they're in.  I don't put whole files in there; I just extract the pieces that I tend to forget and pop them in there.

They do tend to build up as time goes on, so just putting the smaller pieces in is much more efficient for fast lookup.